# How do you developers set your paths for templates?

Tags: php, include-path

I thought I would ask in case I could do it a better way.

On my local (WAMP) I have all my website in the www folder. ( `C:\wamp\www` )

Now currently I do this when i include a file:

```
require_once("".$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/lib/config.php");
```

When I am working on local and upload site to a webhost i want to ensure the paths don't breakI

Could someone please tell me if I should be doing it this way?

I want to ensure maximum compatibility; meaning that paths won't break if I, for example, move site from local to whatever web host I decided to use or if I, for example, move from one host to another.

Maybe there is a more bullet proof way of doing it?

Comment: Watch out: `DOCUMENT_ROOT` may not be defined in all circumstances, such as when running scripts from a command prompt.

Comment: That's already proofed against server changes. It doesn't deal with relocations in a directory below the DOCUMENT_ROOT of course. For that it's common to use application-wide constants for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually do, is make 1 config file (which might include others) with a few very basic constants:

```
define('PROJECT_ROOT', dirname(dirname(__FILE__))); // or dirname(__DIR__) for PHP 5.3
define('PROJECT_WEB', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
// etc
```

Al my other files/includes will be based on those very simple constants. I will never need relative paths and never the include_path, because both `PROJECT_ROOT` and `PROJECT_WEB` are 'real'/absolute.

Other useful (?) constants would be `PROJECT_LOGIC` and/or `PROJECT_CONTROLLERS` and/or `PROJECT_3RD_PARTY` etc.

Comment: your answer seems the most efficent and practial call for me. I do something similar on where my config file contains constants for site name, site email, website address and my conig.php also includes() other files like header.inc.php, sidebar.inc.php, functions.inc.php, db.inc.php, paths.inc.php. So essentially i only ever then have to have 2 includes on each new page i create for site which is config.php and footer.inc.php and even the footer is like include($footer_var) Thanks phplover

Answer (score 2):

The problem with using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is that it will break if you move your PHP scripts up or down a directory level. Instead use this:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/lib/config.php");
```

`__FILE__` is the absolute path of the script. `dirname()` removes the last path component (the script filename) so you can append other path components to it, like `/lib/config.php` or `/../../lib/config.php` or whatever. This will work everywhere.

PHP 5.3 introduced a shorthand for `dirname(__FILE__)`, called `__DIR__`, but this doesn't work in <5.3.

Comment: this wont work if hes including the file from `/index.php` and from `/dir/dir2/index.php`

Comment: @Galen, can you explain what you mean?

Comment: getting the directory of a file located at `/dir/dir2/` would run `require(dir/lib/config.php)`

Answer (score 2):

You should see [Include path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path). For that [set_include_path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) is useful.

Comment: To have more than 1 `include_path` is very expensive. Realpaths are better/faster.

Answer (score 1):

That works fine for including the config file (although i would get rid of the beginning quotes)

```
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/lib/config.php" );
```

This is really the only way to do it if you are including the config file from a bunch of different directories.

On bigger project id say that "most" developers have a [front controller](http://www.phppatterns.com/docs/design/the_front_controller_and_php) that all scripts are loaded from. This front controller loads the config file and since its the same file always including the config file there's no need for `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.

Comment: thanks for the link, very interesting about the front controller, has brought up more questions that i am researching in more depth. Thanks!